# Odd hot water problem: stops & starts with hammer then repeat

Tags: plumbing, water-hammer

Hse built 1870 w all pipes replaced w copper 17yrs ago. All hot faucets thru-out start flowing when opened then shortly stop flowing; then a loud hammer-like noise thru-out house can be heard; then repeat! Heater is AO Smith, 17yrs old in good shape. This is a recent development. Never came across in 40yrs working on these systems. There is not a single hammer arrester in hse. Please help!

Comment: Have you ever removed/check for any sediment from the hot water tank?

Comment: Not my hse and no, it was never done. Tomorrow going to check some of the aerators on faucets to check for calcium flakes but there are no typical sediment sounds coming from heater. I could do that but draining deposits after 17 yrs is risky itself due to exposing weaknesses in the metal and possibly resulting in leaks.  Hell, if a new heater is necessary that's OK but I don't want to do that and not solve the problem. So far I've not talked w anyone whose had this issue. Weird.

Comment: 17 years is a decent life for tanks, especially if no maintenance.  It sounds like a floating blockage.  Open a tap and then rapid stop of flowing water.  It would be from the tank to the first elbow or restriction in the line if all taps act this way.  Sediment might be one cause, loose solder another, or we need a real plumber to tell us the right reason.

Comment: Hey, thanks for response. You gave me a couple ideas.

Comment: Any other thoughts/ideas? Heading to job within 2hrs or so and will report back findings.

Comment: After isolating the heater by removing the hot-side house supply and connecting a separate shut off valve, I was able to discharge hot water thru this  valve and found the same symptom of water hammer coming directly from the heater. I knew then that the problem was the water heater which, when replaced, resolved the mystery.